# Not getting 401 UnAuthorised with Cordova jquery ajax call , Upto Phonegap 1.4 it was working fine

Tags: jquery, cordova, basic-authentication

I have upgraded my project to Phonegap 1.4 to Cordova 1.8.1. Ajax call to webservice was working fine with 401 Unauthorized , when I am passing invalid username / password in Phonegap 1.4.

After up gradation it is not working , I am not getting any response and web service stay there.

If change code to Phonegap 1.4 , it starts working.

Please help

Comment: using cordova 1.8.1 also. When I use HTTP Authentication (Basic), I dont get any error callbacks. Both IOS and Android just finish the application with an timeout error.

Answer (score 6):

I've had this problem for the last couple months and finally figured it out.

First of all, the temporary workaround that we used was to implement a timeout period on the request. That worked, but the response was always a 404. We didn't know if it actually failed authentication, or if our services were down. Not an acceptable workaround for our system.

Finally, after MUCH googling, I found the actual problem.

When a 401 gets returned, (which is a Basic Authentication, authentication failure), it adds a header to the response, called "WWW-Authenticate". This tells the browser to prompt the user to try and login. iOS webview doesn't know what to do with that, so that's why the application hangs.

From your service, all you need to do is remove the WWW-Authenticate header, and you should start to see the 401's in your error function.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem. If you pass incorrect credentials and use

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    timeout: 5000, // Some timeout value that makes sense
    ...
});
```

then the error callback is called with `{"readyState":0,"status":0,"statusText":"timeout"}`. In that case you would have to guess that the real error is the HTTP 401.

Alternatively you can use

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    async: false, // :-(
    ...
});
```

and your error callback will get something like `{"readyState":4,"responseText":"<html>...</html>","status":401,"statusText":"Unauthorized"}` back.

Comment: Looks like this is still a bug (to be fair, it results from iOS 'swallowing' the responses) in Cordova 3.1.0: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2415

Comment: Thank you for this as I spent a couple hours trying to track down what was wrong.  It is still a bug / issue in the latest versions of Cordova for iOS.  Using the async option when on iOS fixes the issue and allows the capture of a 401 condition from the server.

Comment: ok, there is another problem: if the Ajax request was terminated with Async = false with status code 401, the server got two requests at once.
This is dramatic in the sense that two logon attempts are registered at the same time and the user is therefore rather blocked.