# Angular not getting response when it's a non-200

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, cordova

I've impelmented the httpInterceptor found [here](http://beletsky.net/2013/11/simple-authentication-in-angular-dot-js-app.html).

If my Basic Auth header has valid credentials, everything works fine, but if I get back a 401, then the application just hangs and I never receive a response.

Here's my interceptor:

```
angular.module('TDE').factory('httpInterceptor', function httpInterceptor ($q, $window, $location) {
    return function (promise) {
        var success = function (response) {
            //window.logger.logIt("httpInterceptor received a good response: " + response);
            return response;
        };

        var error = function (response) {
            //window.logger.logIt("httpInterceptor received an error: " + response);

            if (response.status === 401) {
                $location.url('/login');
            }

            return $q.reject(response);
        };

        return promise.then(success, error);
    };
});
```

Declaring the httpInterceptor in app.js

```
angular.module('TDE', []);

var TDE = angular.module('TDE', ['ux', 'ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'TDE', 'hmTouchEvents', 'infinite-scroll', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.sortable']);

TDE.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('httpInterceptor');

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {})
        .when('/login', { templateUrl: "Views/Login/login.html", controller: "LoginController" })
```

And my authenticate method

```
authenticate: function (user, password) {
//            window.logger.logIt("serviceAccount: " + $rootScope.serviceAccount);
            window.logger.logIt("In authenticate...");

            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var encoded = encoder.encode($rootScope.serviceAccount);
            //var encoded = encoder.encode(user + ":" + password);

            if (user && password) {
                window.logger.logIt("We've got a username and password...");

                $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic ' + encoded;

                sessionStorage.setItem('Authorization', $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization);

                var url = $rootScope.serviceBaseUrl + "login/authenticate";

                window.logger.logIt(url);

                $http({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: {
                        "Username": user,
                        "Password": password,
                        "AccessToken": ""
                    },
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    }
                })
                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    window.logger.logIt("We've got a response (success)...");

                    if (data.IsAuthenticated) {
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                        session.setSession();
                    } else {
                        deferred.reject(status);
                    }
                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                    window.logger.logIt("We've got a response (error)...");

                    $dialogservice.showMessage("Authentication Error", "Return Code: " + status);
                    deferred.reject(status);
                });
            } else {
                window.logger.logIt("We've got a response...");

                deferred.reject(401);
            }

            return deferred.promise;
        },
```

You'll see that in my Authenticate method, there are two lines that I'm testing:

```
var encoded = encoder.encode($rootScope.serviceAccount);
```

and

```
var encoded = encoder.encode(user + ":" + password);
```

We are REQUIRED to use Basic Authentication (which is over SSL). Right now, all I'm testing is that I can receive a 401 back. If I use the $rootScope.serviceAccount (which is working), I get a 200 response right away. But if I purposely send a bad username/password, I NEVER get a response, the application just sits there.

**Edit:** Ok, I've updated my code to the following, and still getting the same behavior:

```
angular
    .module('TDE')
    .config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q) {
        return {
            'request': function (config) {
                window.logger.logIt("Request is being sent...");

                var headers = config.headers;

                if (!headers.Authorization) {
                    headers.Authorization = sessionStorage.getItem('Authorization');
                }

                return config || $q.when(config);
            },

            'response': function (response) {
                window.logger.logIt("got a good response...");

                return response;
            },

            'responseError': function (rejection) {
                window.logger.logIt("responseError error...");

                return $q.reject(rejection);
            },
        };
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Which version of angularjs are you using?

Comment: The Angular version is v1.2.2

Comment: The `$httpProvider.responseInterceptors` is deprecated, please consider coverting it into a general `$httpProvider.intercepters`. For the problem, is the `success` and `error` callback in the httpInterceptor ever get called for a 401 response?

Comment: @runTarm no, I never got anything when the 401 is getting returned. I have verified that 401 IS getting returned by testing from Fiddler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, again, PhoneGap is the issue!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060619/not-getting-401-unauthorised-with-cordova-jquery-ajax-call-upto-phonegap-1-4-i)

[Example 2](http://me.eekay.nl/index.php/2014/cordovaphonegap-and-the-missing-callback-for-401-unauthorized/)

[Example 3](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2415)

[Example 4](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2962)

Answer (score 0):

Try this interceptor:

```
.factory('httpInterceptor', function(){         
     return {
         request : function(yourRequestConfig){

            var returnPromise = $q.defer();

            $http(yourRequestConfig).then(function(response) {
                console.log("successful response from server ", response);
                returnPromise.resolve(response);

            }, function(someReason) {
                console.log("failure response from server", reason);
                returnPromise.reject(reason);
            });
            return returnPromise.promise;
         }
     }
});
```

used as

```
httpInterceptor.request(request config).then(returnValue){
    console.log('inside controller', returnValue);
});
```

where request config is something like:

```
var requestConfig = {
    method: "GET",
    url: "localhost:8080/getStuff"
};
```

Comment: essentially, instead of using $http use a service to make all your http calls, it's clean and works the same way and at the same speed as an interceptor.

Comment: The requests are not the problem, it's receiving only the 401's that we can't catch...